# How to split to the right of a number?

Tags: ruby, regex, split

I'm trying to use Ruby to split to the right of a number.

For example: H2SO4
How do you do this?
I'd like to output `["H2", "SO4"]`

`x.split(/\d+/)` yields: ["H", "SO"]

`x.split(//)` yields: ["H", "2", "S", "O", "4"]

Both cool but not exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: Which reminds me: "Billy was a chemist, but Billy is no more.  For what he thought was H2O was H2SO4"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
x.scan(/[A-za-z]*\d+/)
```

This means break it into groups, each of which contains 0 or more letters, then 1 or more digits.  Or if the non-digits can be anything:

```
x.scan(/\D*\d+/)
```